# Javascript board game: looking for optimization

Tags: android, javascript, optimization

#### I posted this question on stackoverflow before but received no answers so I decided to post it here and see if someone could suggest me something.

I'm working on a html/javascript game for android. It's a board game which does the following.
It has tiles of different colors and user can place one tile (chosen programatically) on the board. If we get 4 or more tiles of the same color/shape we score some points and these tiles will disappear. The tiles above the removed tiles will replace them and new tiles will be added to the empty places. The image below shows how it works **(this is just an example, the real board can have different dimensions)**:

[image]

The Tiles are `<img>` elements with their ids stored in an array which I use to check for matches and replacement.

It all works pretty well but once the new tiles are added to board I need to examine the whole board to check if new matches are avalable. And I want some advice here, because examining the whole board can be really slow. Is there a way I can do this efficiently?
Here's what I thought about doing:
[image]

Given the previous example, I thought about examining only the elements in the red area, i.e. only the elements that have been moved or added. It can be effective if the tiles move vertically, as I'll only have to check the moved/added tiles and it'll give me the new matches. But in case where I remove tiles horizontally it can be problematic, because if these tiles are at the bottom i'll have to examine the whole board and i confront the same problem.

Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: I didn't add any code because it simply consists of checking the lines and columns for a given tile and look for matches. But if needed I can provide it.

EDIT: Adding `horizontalMatchCheck` function that for a given index checks for matches horizontally. It's the same thing for vertical check.

```
function horizontalMatchCheck(itemId) {
    hArray = new Array();
    if (rightMatch(itemId)) {
        var index = itemId + 1;
        hArray.push(itemId + 1);
        while (rightMatch(index)) {
            hArray.push(index + 1);
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (leftMatch(itemId)) {
        var index = itemId - 1;
        hArray.push(itemId - 1);
        while (leftMatch(index)) {
            hArray.push(index - 1);
            index--;
        }
    }
    //if >=4 matches found I replace the indexes with 5 (because no other tile can have this id) which'll then be removed and shifted.
    if (hArray.length >= 3) {
        hArray.push(itemId);
        for (var i = 0; i < hArray.length; i++) {
            board[hArray[i]] = items.length;
        }
    }
    else
        hArray = new Array();
}

function rightMatch(pos) 
      return (!isRight(pos) && board[(pos+1)] == current) ? 1 : 0 ;
function leftMatch(pos)
      return (!isLeft(pos) && board[(pos-1)] == current) ? 1 : 0 ;
```

Comment: Is examining a 4x4 board really that slow? Store your data as a two dimensional array, and simply run through each column, as well as each row checking for color matches. If that doesn't work, you could try storing your data by color, and checking their position data for adjacent tiles.

Comment: Post some of your matching code, most likely it can be improved. Are you using jquery?

Comment: @Evan the 4x4 board was just an example as i stated. if it's a 10x10 board examining each tile can be slow.

Comment: @petervaz I'll add my code

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the full code but it seems simple enough. The only thing I see is that you don't need to match right and left, just match right ignoring the last row.

Comment: @petervaz ok but if for a tile in the middle of the board i have 2 tiles on left and 2 on right, if i only check on right i will not have a match as i'll only have three same tiles.

Comment: Do you think that the code is too slow, or do you know that the code is too slow? It doesn't seem like something that should cause a modern phone to halt noticeably.

Comment: @eBusiness I know that the code is slow, i've already tested checking each tile of the board and some times it halts for some seconds to calculate.

Comment: @Anila I'll show you a working class for gem matching game I'm creating. It is in java, but perhaps you can draw some inspiration from it >> [here](http://pastebin.com/4nPW6570) <<

Comment: @petervaz thanks a lot! I'll check it right away. It is really very kind of you. I'll get back with more questions if needed.

Comment: @Anila It halts for some seconds, that is what you know, I don't think this code is causing it.

Comment: @eBusiness you think so? I reached to this conclusion because without these tests my game works quite fast. But I'll do some more tests anyway and see if your idea is right.

Comment: @Anila Try timing the loop where you make the calls, removing and adding code and trying to gauge the effect is a really bad way of finding slow code.

Comment: @eBusiness that's not exactly what i meant :p but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @petervaz your code helped me achieve my goal +1 for that. and thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit that I don't exactly understand what your algorithm is for finding matches right now, but I can tell you that there is an easy O(n) method that makes as many passes over the board as directions you want to check in if all you want to check in is straight lines.  This is not what you are looking for if you want these matches to include all touching shapes of the same color or shape, this only checks for those that appear in a straight line.

Assuming you have your `board` in a two dimensional array where each shape has a color,  shape and a property "isInRun" it is:

```
var shapeRun = [];
var colorRun = [];
for (var i = 0; i < boardX; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < boardY; j++) {
        var cell = board[i][j];
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            var currentShape = cell.shape;
            var currentColor = cell.color;
            shapeRun.push(cell);
            colorRun.push(cell);
        } else {
            if (j > 0 && cell.shape == currentShape) {
                shapeRun.push(cell);
            } else {
                if (shapeRun.length >= runLength) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < shapeRun.length; k++) {
                        shapeRun[k].isInRun = true;
                    }
                }
                currentShape = cell.shape;
                shapeRun = [cell];
            }
            if (j > 0 && cell.color == currentColor) {
                colorRun.push(cell);
            } else {
                if (colorRun.length >= runLength) {
                    for (var k = 0; k < colorRun.length; k++) {
                        colorRun[k].isInRun = true;
                    }
                }
                currentColor = cell.color;
                colorRun = [cell];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This scans each row for "runs" of more than `runLength` shapes and marks them as belonging to a group of matches by setting `isInRun` to true. Do this again but switch

```
var cell = board[i][j];
```

to

```
var cell = board[j][i];
```

To check in the other direction.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/PaRwy/5/) for an example (only tested in Chrome).  This creates a random board every 5 seconds with 3 types of shapes and 3 types of colors and then highlights all the matches of 4 or more.  You can play around with the parameters at the top of the javascript to change the dimensions of the board or the number of colors and shapes.

I've run this on my phone (a Galaxy Nexus) and I had to bump to board size up to 50x50 to even measure the time it takes.

Comment: thanks a lot! I really appreciate all the help I'm getting from here.

Comment: thanks to your directions and those of petervaz I got what I wanted. I'm accepting this answer but the credit goes to both of you. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're using the DOM as a general-purpose data structure. I would not recommend this approach.

You should separate the game state and rendering, into pieces of logic which are independent of each other. Don't use the DOM as a data store, and don't store references to DOM elements inside your "game state" data.

Having said that, I would also suggest that you consider using a canvas instead of DOM elements. But that's an implementation detail and may not be relevant to your problem.

If you have a simple 2d JS array, with primitive types (integers are good) as elements, it CANNOT be slow to do these lookups, even with a large grid.

In summary:

- Store your board as a 2d array (array-of-arrays). Primitive types (integer) are best, but objects could be ok too.
- Do not keep DOM references inside your game state (if you choose to use DOM elements to render tiles, look them up each time you need them)

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm new to this (game and web dev) that's why i keep mising these things. I'll keep it in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't codereview.stackexchange.com, but...

There's no obvious reason for `hArray` to exist. You could just use two local variables, a lower bound and an upper bound, both of which are initialised to `itemId` (which surely should be called `itemIndex`?) and expand them in different directions with simplified versions of the loops.

OTOH this method looks a bit dubious per se. A single scan through the entire row would certainly be quicker than a flood-fill from each cell.

If you really want speed above all else, I believe JavaScript's regex support is quite good...